DataTables 2.0 in Wordpress Plugin Admin Area
I would like to implement DataTables2 in my WordPress plugin. I started from test table to check if it works:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooSKU Updater
Description: A plugin to manage SKUs, quantities, and prices using DataTables.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

function woosku_updater_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue jQuery first
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js', array(), null, true);

    // Enqueue DataTables after jQuery
    wp_enqueue_style('datatables-css', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/css/dataTables.dataTables.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('datatables-js', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    // Initialize DataTables
    wp_add_inline_script('datatables-js', '
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#woosku-table").DataTable();
        });
    ');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woosku_updater_enqueue_scripts');


// Add the WooSKU Updater admin menu
function woosku_updater_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'WooSKU Updater',      // Page title
        'SKU Updater',         // Menu title
        'manage_options',      // Required capability
        'woosku-updater',      // Menu slug
        'woosku_updater_page', // Function to display the admin page content
        'dashicons-update',    // Icon
        100                    // Position
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'woosku_updater_menu');

// Callback function for the admin page content
function woosku_updater_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>WooSKU Updater</h1>
        <p>Manage your SKUs, quantities, and prices.</p>
        <table id="woosku-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr><td>SKU001</td><td>10</td><td>£15.00</td></tr>
                <tr><td>SKU002</td><td>5</td><td>£25.50</td></tr>
                <tr><td>SKU003</td><td>8</td><td>£12.75</td></tr>
                <tr><td>SKU004</td><td>20</td><td>£8.99</td></tr>
                <tr><td>SKU005</td><td>15</td><td>£10.50</td></tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}

It creates example table, but it doesn't load all Datatables files. The error I have is

load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.7:4
   POST https://example.com.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)


And the code connected to this error:
<script type='text/javascript'>
                (function($) {

                    //(Re)starts the background worker thread
                    function blcDoWork() {
                        $.post("https://example.com.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {
                            'action': 'blc_work',
                            '_ajax_nonce': 'a5213e0ea6'
                        });
                    }

                    //Call it the first time
                    blcDoWork();

                    //Then call it periodically every X seconds
                    setInterval(blcDoWork, 421000);

                }
                )(jQuery);
            </script>

Any thoughts? Thank you.

The wp_enqueue_scripts hook is for scripts you want to embed in the frontend; to embed scripts in the backend, you should use admin_enqueue_scripts. And where is the blc_work AJAX action getting defined?
